# Veracode flaw CWE-93: Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences ('CRLF Injection')

Tags: java, security, veracode

I've been working on a veracode flaw which I believe has already been fixed since we are already doing an Encode.forJava. But it is still being scanned as a flaw. Can someone please help me if I missed  something? Here is the code snippet:

```
InternetAddress[] addressCC = { new InternetAddress(Encode.forJava(strCc)) };
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, addressCC);
```

Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: Are you using `org.owasp.encoder.Encode.forJava` or a different implementation? Veracode lists the OWASP method as a cleansing function for CWE-93, but it won't recognise a different Encode.

Comment: Yes, I am using org.owasp.encoder.

Comment: I am thinking that the reason maybe since we are using an array for the addressCC that is why it is not being recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the plural form method `setRecipients()`.

**Instead:**

If you only have one email address to add you can use this:

```
msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(Encode.forJava(address)));
```

If you need to add multiple addresses you can call `addRecipient()` multiple times like this:

```
for (String address: recipients) {
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(Encode.forJava(address)));
}
```